# How to update a component without refresh/reload in react-native when we fetch/update data from firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am updating some data in firebase collection from component A in my react native App. For Example, I am updating the name parameter in collection X in the firebase. The update of a name is done from component A. Component B is fetching the name from the same collection X. But to see the changes in component B, I have to reload the app or refresh the app again. But I want to see the changes without doing a refresh or reload the app.

component A

```
    async setName(){
    await firestore()
    .collection('set_name')
    .doc(auth().currentUser.uid)
    .update({
      name: this.state.name}).then( () => {
        console.log('name updated')
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
}
```

component B

```
    componentDidMount(){
      this.getName();
    }

    async getName(){
    let name;
    await firestore()
    .collection('set_name')
    .doc(auth().currentUser.uid)
    .get().then(function(doc){
        this.setState({name:doc.data()}))
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
}
```

I can fetch data from firebase in component B but to see changes I have to reload the component. But I don't want reloading to see any changes in component B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use onSnapShot function to get real time updates and set the component state.

Try this way

Component B

```
componentDidMount(){
   firestore()
    .collection('set_name')
    .doc(auth().currentUser.uid)
    .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
        this.setState({name:doc.data()}))
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen for the real time updates from firestore. When you perform a write, your listeners will be notified with the new data before the data is sent to the backend. So instead of using `.get()` in component B you can modify the function as following.

```
 db.collection('set_name')
    .doc(auth().currentUser.uid)
    .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
       this.setState({name:doc.data()}))
    });
```